# How do I modify hooks created by the feathersjs generator?

Tags: feathersjs

I used the feathers-cli to generate a service and am trying to modify the generated `<service>.hooks` file to disallow the `find` method of my service. I tried various iterations of this:

```
const { disallow } = require('feathers-hooks-common');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [hook => disallow()],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
};
```

But I get the following error:

`before hook for 'find' method returned invalid hook object`

The documentation frustratingly doesn't show examples based on the generator created `<service>.hooks` file which is kind of annoying and weird.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do it:

```
find: [
  disallow()
]
```

That should work! If you want to learn more about it: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks-common.html#disallow

Hope it works!